# How to split a string into a single column with multiple rows?

Tags: sql, exasol

I have a column named fruits:

```
CREATE TABLE fruits (fruits varchar(50));
INSERT INTO analytics.fruits
values
    ('apple')
    ('banana')
    ('lemon')
    ('kiwi')
;
```

| fruits |
| --- |
| apple, banana, lemon, kiwi |

I want to split that column into multiple rows, one row per element in the string:

| fruits |
| --- |
| apple |
| banana |
| lemon |
| kiwi |

How can I do that in Exasol?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Exasol but maybe with this code that works you can figure out, how to work with Exasol

```
WITH RECURSIVE num AS
  (SELECT 1 AS n )

SELECT 
 concat(ucase(substring(trim(substring_index(substring_index(name, ",", n), ",", -1)), 1, 1)), 
 lcase(substring(trim(substring_index(substring_index(name, ",", n), ",", -1)), 2))) AS Fruits
FROM fruits f
JOIN num ON n <= length(name) - length(replace(name, ",", "")) + 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

This code is from MySQL

Comment: Thanks but does not work with Exasol: `SQL Error [0A000]: Feature not supported: WITH RECURSIVE`